# The limits of recursive sequences of different types of means - my solution + challenge

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Consider the sequence $a_{n+2}=f(a_1,a_2)$ where $f(x,y)$ is the mean of $x, y$ (geometric/arithmetic/harmonic) and $a_1,a_2$ are positive real numbers.

In detail:

Geometric - $a_{n+2}=\sqrt{a_{n+1}a_n}$

Arithmetic - $a_{n+2}={1 \over 2}(a_{n+1}+a_n)$

Harmonic - $a_{n+2}={2 \over {a_{n+1}^{-1}+a_n}^{-1}}$

Now, it's easy to show that each sequence converges (though if you have an interesting method to show that, share it with us!), but the trick is to calculate the limit. Here I give my way to compute these limits and challenge you to do so for a recursive sequence that each step takes the mean of its three or more previous element, namely $a_{n+N}=f(a_{n+N-1},a_{n+N-2},...,a_{n})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution (I used the notation $L=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$). One just have to calculate the average of $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ and give $a_{n+1}$ a double weight:

$$GEOMETRIC$$  $$a_{n+1}\sqrt{a_n}=a_{n}\sqrt{a_{n-1}}=...=a_{2}\sqrt{a_1}$$
$$ => \lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n+1}\sqrt{a_n}=L\sqrt{L}=L^{3\over 2}=a_{2}\sqrt{a_1}$$
$$ => L=({a_{2}\sqrt{a_1}})^{2 \over 3}$$

$$ARITHMETIC$$  $$a_{n+1}+{1 \over 2}{a_n}=a_{n}+{1 \over 2}{a_{n-1}}=...=a_{2}+{1 \over 2}{a_1}$$
$$ => \lim_{n\to\infty} (a_{n+1}+{1 \over 2}{a_n})=L+{1 \over 2}{L}={3\over 2}L=a_{2}+{1 \over 2}{a_1}$$
$$ => L={2\over 3}(a_{2}+{1 \over 2}{a_1})$$

$$HARMONIC$$  $$\frac{2}{2a_{n+1}^{-1}+{a_n}^{-1}}=\frac{2}{\frac{2}{\frac{2}{a_{n}^{-1}+a_{n-1}^{-1}}}+{a_n}^{-1}}=\frac{2}{2a_{n}^{-1}+{a_{n-1}}^{-1}}=...=\frac{2}{2a_{2}^{-1}+{a_1}^{-1}}$$
$$ => \lim_{n\to\infty} (\frac{2}{2a_{n+1}^{-1}+{a_n}^{-1}})=\frac{2}{2L^{-1}+{L}^{-1}}={2\over 3}L=\frac{2}{2a_{2}^{-1}+{a_1}^{-1}}$$
$$ => L={3\over 2}(\frac{2}{2a_{2}^{-1}+{a_1}^{-1}})$$